# Does changing nav content regularly impact SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a nav, it has links to parent categories of my shopping site.

I also have space on this nav and would like to highlight some popular child categories of my site.

I'd like to switch these child links around now and again for different child categories.

All categories and child categories feature in my site map.

Will changing part of my main nav's content every other week or so have any impact on SEO?

Comment: Short answer? Yes. Navigation is an important signal to what the site owner feels is most important. If you change it, you are changing what you are telling Google is important. As long as you are pointing to what is important, then all is well. However, making rapid changes as you describe will muddle things and I doubt Google will keep up. All and all, do what is right for users and do not worry about it. Still, I do not recommend changing navigation that often. It may not be good for returning users. Cheers!!

Comment: Changing 1 slot of 6 or 2 slots of 10 probably won't confuse Google much though.   Amazon has featured products on its home page that change daily.

Comment: so far i understand, you want to change not a productpresentation on the page, but links in your navigation menu? for my feeling it could be disappoint for users, specially for recurring, who are your best friends. Don't do it - you'll get never enough benefits from this tactic to make good all of wastages your site gets from it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller There is a world of difference between how Google treats Amazon and the rest of us. If the OP was Wikipedia, then I would agree. Still, I recommend doing what the OP feels is best for their users and ignoring SEs (for the better part anyway).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Now that I think about it, the only thing missing would be signals that would normally be considered important. However, if there is benefit to changing the navigation often, then Oh well! Google may never catch up. Who knows? The balance lies somewhere between causing users confusion and not getting an advantage from Google to Nirvana. I am not sure we can really say where the balance is without looking over the OPs shoulder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sub-categories to the navigation of your site is not a bad for SEO. But try to keep the navigation simple and easy to use. If your customers can find the products they are looking for, that increases your chances of making a sale. But use this space wisely and keep the main navigation links consistent in between updates.

Take a look at major Online stores their nav changes often with links to promotions and featured products.